# End up having a NoneType error on comand prompt

Tags: python, pandas, h5py

my problem comes from a code that was developed to use pandas as main library to read from archives. But since I have my data coded on a .mat file I have to use h5py. So my code changed is something like this:

```
    root_dir_dataset = cur_root_dir + '/' + archive_name + '/' + dataset_name 

    mat=h5py.File( root_dir_dataset + '/' + dataset_name + '_TRAIN.mat', 'r')
    y_train = np.transpose(mat['F'][:1000,[1]]) #df_train.values[:, 0]
    y_test = np.transpose(mat['F'][1000:2000,[2]]) #df_test.values[:, 0]
    x_train = np.transpose(mat['F'][:1000,[1]]) #df_train #.drop(columns=[0])
    x_test = np.transpose(mat['F'][1000:2000,[2]]) #df_test #.drop(columns=[0])
```

Then we compute the mean and std of the _test and _train of x and we copy all the arrays like this:

```
datasets_dict[dataset_name] = (x_train.copy(), y_train.copy(), x_test.copy(), y_test.copy())
```

This is all inside a function, we I call that function on my main code I define the next class:

```
def fit_classifier():
x_train = datasets_dict[dataset_name][0]
y_train = datasets_dict[dataset_name][1]
x_test = datasets_dict[dataset_name][2]
y_test = datasets_dict[dataset_name][3]

nb_classes = len(np.unique(np.concatenate((y_train, y_test), axis=0)))

# transform the labels from integers to one hot vectors
enc = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
enc.fit(np.concatenate((y_train, y_test), axis=0).reshape(-1, 1))
y_train = enc.transform(y_train.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
y_test = enc.transform(y_test.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()

# save orignal y because later we will use binary
y_true = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)

if len(x_train.shape) == 2:  # if univariate
    # add a dimension to make it multivariate with one dimension 
    x_train = x_train.reshape((x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
    x_test = x_test.reshape((x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]
classifier = create_classifier(classifier_name, input_shape, nb_classes, output_directory)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, y_true)
```

And in the end when I call the main code with the conda prompt it appears the next message:

File ".....", line 43, in fit_classifier classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, y_true)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'

I don't see the problem here, may someone could tell me if there's some mistake I'm making. I thought that since my problem is that the archive is on .mat there may be a form to change from.mat to a pandas dataframe respecting the variables of the .mat archive?

Comment: Does `create_classifier` return anything?

Comment: Yeah depending on which case it returns something like this :

def create_classifier(classifier_name, input_shape, nb_classes, output_directory, verbose=False): 
        if classifier_name == 'mcnn':
               from classifiers import mcnn
               return mcnn.Classifier_MCNN(output_directory, verbose)